# How to use multiple entry files to control routing in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

At present, I have the following routes

```
Route::post('/report', [App\Http\Controllers\ServerController::class, 'report'])->name('report');
Route::get('/report', [App\Http\Controllers\ServerController::class, 'getData'])->name('get_data');

Route::get('/other',[App\Http\Controllers\ServerController::class, 'other'])->name('other');
Route::get('/other2',[App\Http\Controllers\ServerController::class, 'other2'])->name('other2');
Route::get('/other3',[App\Http\Controllers\ServerController::class, 'other3'])->name('other3');
...
```

I create `report.php` in the `public` directory

I want to bind the get and post requests of `report.php` to `report` and `get_data`

But I didn't find a similar explanation in the official document

What should I do?

Update:2021-05-21

I found a solution, but it didn't look elegant
Are there any other solutions?

```
<?php

// this is public/report.php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));


if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__ . '/../storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}



require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']  = "/report.php/report";
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI'] = "/report.php/report";

// var_dump($_SERVER);

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: What's the reason? What's wrong with the current approach?

Comment: Do you want to create a file routes/report.php for routing?

Comment: @brombeer 

I want to bind access to public / report. PHP to report and get_ data

Instead of accessing / report directly

Comment: @biswajit-biswas I want to bind access to public / report. PHP to report and get_ data Instead of accessing / report directly